# Print number patterns in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, logic

I want to print numbers in pattern as below also I need this to print using only one for loop not in if condition inside for loop.

If I give `s = 7` the output pattern would be `7, 5, 3, 1, 3, 5, 7`

If `s=6` then output is `6, 4, 2, 4, 6`

This is what I tried but not successful.

```js
const s = 7, b = 2

for (x = s, d = b; x > 0 && x <= 7; x -= 2) {
  console.log(x)
}
```

I don't want to use any pre-built libraries to achieve this such as `Math.abs()`

Comment: FYI, this creates a global `x` and `d` variables

Comment: Anything would be great

Comment: you can reverse your output array and merge. Is that acceptable?

Comment: no array is not allowed here, only for loop with some maths, to reverse it you need if condition right, that's also not allowed

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't meet your stated requirement right above this comment: "to reverse it you need if condition right, that's also not allowed" -- that's exactly what the code, `step = x + step <= 0 ? -step : step`,  is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ternary operator:

```js
const s = 10, b = 2

for (x = s, step = -b; x <= s; step = x + step <= 0 ? -step : step, x += step) {
  console.log(x)
}
```

Comment: Can you write the same for Java as well

Comment: Can you write without Math class

Comment: @AmalaAmala it is basically the same in Java.

Comment: @marace I need without Math class and such pre-built libraries' help

Comment: @AmalaAmala can you define functions? E.g. `function sign(x) {return x > 0 ? 1 : (x < 0 ? -1 : 0)}`

Comment: You can use the same logic in for loop instead using the function.

Comment: Wouldn't using ternary operator be the same as using `if`?

Comment: @AmalaAmala yes we can, but ternary operator is basically an `if else`

Comment: @maraca when I give const s = 10, b = 2, this is not working

Comment: @AmalaAmala yes that's why the sign of 0 is 0, do you want to print the 0 or not?

Comment: const s = 10, b = 2, then the output would be 10,8,6,4,2,4,6,8,10 with the different value 2

Comment: @AmalaAmala no problem with ternary operator, see added snippet

Comment: @maraca Thanks a ton bro, this is the answer to my question. exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @AmalaAmala https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @AmalaAmala the problem with the edit is, that 2nd part uses ternary operator then too, so we could delety it completely

Comment: You are a Ninja in programming. Tc.

Comment: @maraca can you help me to print this in ascending order as well.

Comment: @maraca can you answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64694810/print-number-patterns-in-javascript-ascending

Answer (score 1):

```js
var s = 7, b = 2, x, d;
var front = " ", back = " ";

for (x = s, d = b; x - b > 0 ; x -= b) {
    front = front + " " + x; 
    back = x + " " + back;
}
console.log(front + " " + x + " " + back);
```

Comment: Nice idea, but if you get it to run it will print 7, 5, 3, 1, 1, 3, 5, 7 (two 1s).

Comment: No the 1 should not be duplicated

Comment: @AmalaAmala:How about this?

Comment: Why there is string

Comment: @AmalaAmala: This is a fun question but you are changing the terms of the question too much. You should post all the conditions at once in the question itself.

Comment: @AmalaAmala: My code is in c++. in javascript it would be straight forward res = "".

Comment: @AmalaAmala: C'mon, you edited the post to `I don't want to use any pre-built libraries to achieve this such as Math.abs()` later when people started answering. Could you please convert my code to javascript?

Comment: @AmalaAmala: You missed out the `res` while converting my code to javascript

Answer (score 0):

This works for both even and odd numbers:

```
const s = 8, b = 2

for (x=s,step = b; x <=s ; (x===1 || x===2) ? (step = -b, x = x-step ): x= x-step) {
    console.log(x)
}
```

What I have done is that in the increment/ decrement block when x equals to 1 for odd numbers or when x equals to 2 for even numbers the step is being changed from positive to negative.

To print the numbers in ascending order :

```
const s = 10

for ( x=0,step=1; x!== -1 ; x===s ? (step = -1, x = x+step): x= x+step) {
    console.log(x)
}
```

Comment: can you do it to print in ascending order also?

Comment: It is possible. Can you share a sample output that you are expecting.

Comment: if s  = 10, output 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0

Comment: ```const s = 10, b = 2

for ( x=0,step=1; x!== -1 ; x===s ? (step = -1, x = x+step): x= x+step) {
    console.log(x)
}

```