# Print number patterns in JavaScript - Ascending and Descending in same loop

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I want to print numbers in pattern as below also I need this to print using only one for loop not in if condition inside for loop.

If I give s = 7 the output pattern would be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0

This is what I tried but not successful.

```
for (x = s, step = -b, i = 0; x <= s; step = x + step <= 0 ? -step : step, x += step, i++, step) {
    console.log(x, i, step)
}
```

I've already asked a question for this descending order with a different pattern also this is a different question that's the reason I created another question

[Print number patterns in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64692314/print-number-patterns-in-javascript/64693469?noredirect=1#comment114387312_64693469)

I don't want to use any pre-built libraries to achieve this such as Math.abs()

Comment: so, you can't figure it out given the answer in your other question? it's a simple variation of the answer you chose in the other question ... `const s = 7, b = 1;

for (x = 0, step = b; x >= 0; step = x + step <= s ? step : -step, x += step) {
  console.log(x)
}`

Comment: can you do ascending and descending in the same loop with two variables

Comment: probably - did you try?

Answer (score 2):

```js
function printNumbers(s){
   for (i = 0, num = 0; i <= s * 2; ++i <= s ? num++ : num--){
       console.log(num);
   }
}

printNumbers(7);
```

Top down version with steps support:

```js
function printNumbers(s, step){
   for (i = 0, num = s; num <= s; i+= step, i <= s ? num -= step : num += step) {
       console.log(num);
   }
}

printNumbers(7, 2);
```

You can try it with different steps.

Comment: or even `for (i = 0; i <= s * 2; i++) console.log(s - Math.abs(i-s));`

Comment: In this same pattern can you print this also ?
7, 5, 3, 1, 3, 5, 7

Comment: @AmalaAmala - why don't you try youself

Comment: I've tried many but I could not, that's why I asked here please help me

Comment: Can you help me to print 7, 5, 3, 1, 3, 5, 7

Answer (score 0):

```js
// 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0

function print(num) {
  let c = 0
  let output = []
  while(c <= num) {
    output.push(c)
    c++
  }
  
  while(num > 0){
   num--
   output.push(num)
  }
  
  return output.join(',')
}

let o = print(7)

console.log(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
const s = 10
let solution= ''
for ( x=0,step=1; x!== -1 ; x===s ? (step = -1, x = x+step): x= x+step) {
    solution = solution + `${x},`
}
solution = solution.slice(0,-1)
console.log(solution)
```

Comment: Can you help me to print this like this "7,5,3,1,3,5,7" 
for (i = 0, num = 0; i <= s * 2; ++i <= s ? num++ : num--)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a single loop with a correction for values greater than the largest value.

```js
function* print(n, s) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 2 * n; i += s) {
        yield i > n ? 2 * n - i : i;
    }
}

console.log(...print(7, 1));
console.log(...print(7, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Recapping a little bit your requirements:

- Single `for`
- No use of arrays
- No use of `if`

  - for that matter, the ternary operator `(c)?a:b` translates to `if (c) a; else b`
- > If I give s = 7 the output pattern would be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0
- > I don't want to use any pre-built libraries to achieve this such as Math.abs()

Here is a code for that:

```js
let i = 0;
const s = 7;
let stringToPrint = ''+s;
for (i=s-1; i>=0; i--){
    stringToPrint = ''+i+','+stringToPrint+','+i;
}
console.log(stringToPrint)
```